# s2ram_do: Device or resource busy

Tags: debugging, suspend

My system normally suspends to RAM with no problem. But the past few days it has not worked:

```
s2ram -f
s2ram -f -a 1
s2ram -f -a 2
s2ram -f -a 3
s2ram -f -p -m
s2ram -f -p -s
s2ram -f -m
s2ram -f -s
s2ram -f -p
s2ram -f -a 1 -m
s2ram -f -a 1 -s
```

all return:

```
KMS graphics driver is in use, skipping quirks.
s2ram_do: Device or resource busy
```

with this in `dmesg`:

```
[841997.535738] PM: suspend entry (deep)
[841997.535743] PM: suspend exit
```

It goes away when I reboot, but it is bugging me that I cannot figure out what causes it. If `s2ram_do` told me exactly which device or resource that was busy, it might give me a hint.

```
$ s2ram -i
This machine can be identified by:                                                                                    
    sys_vendor   = "Acer"                                                                                             
    sys_product  = "Aspire V3-771"                                                                                    
    sys_version  = "V2.21"                                                                                            
    bios_version = "V2.21"
```