# How can I find out which device or resource is busy?

Tags: devices, cgroups, journalctl

I'm looking for advice troubleshooting an issue related to 'cgroups' on Ubuntu 18.04.

An application (Mullvad) gives the following error in `journalctl`:

```
    [mullvad_daemon][ERROR] Error: Unable to initialize daemon
    Caused by: Unable to initialize split tunneling
    Caused by: Unable to initialize net_cls cgroup instance
    Caused by: EBUSY: Device or resource busy
```

I want to figure out exactly why the `net_cls` cgroup could not be initialized.  The biggest clue is the next line, `EBUSY: Device or resource busy`.  Is there any way of determining which device or resource this refers to?  The information obviously exists -- the system must know which device or resource it was trying to access.  Am I allowed to know what it is?

This is substantially the same question as [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/573134/479639), which has been ignored for the better part of two years.  Perhaps a fresher question with a different context will help.

**EDIT**  Here's some output from `strace -rf` that might be relevant:

```
[pid 25845]      0.000071 poll([{fd=45, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=45, revents=POLLOUT}])
[pid 25845]      0.000062 writev(45, [{iov_base="\20\0\3\0\4\0G\0Meta", iov_len=12}, {iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0}, {iov_base="", iov_len=0}], 3) = 12
[pid 25845]      0.000088 poll([{fd=45, events=POLLIN}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=45, revents=POLLIN}])
[pid 25845]      0.000061 recvmsg(45, {msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="\1\0\177\1\0\0\0\0\246\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", iov_len=4096}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 32
[pid 25845]      0.000081 recvmsg(45, {msg_namelen=0}, 0) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
[pid 25845]      0.000063 recvmsg(45, {msg_namelen=0}, 0) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

There are many repeating blocks of this form in the output.  The "Resource temporarily unavailable" bit makes me think it might be related to "Device or resource not found."

Comment: You should run your application through `strace`.

Comment: @HaukeLaging  Okay, I've done that.  I have 20,000+ lines of output.  The strings "mullvad_daemon", "net_cls", "EBUSY", and "Device or resource busy" don't appear in any of them.  I see no obvious clues about which device or resource is preventing the `net_cls` cgroup from initializing.  What am I looking for?

Comment: Does the problem make the application abort? In that case I would look close to the end for syscalls which failed.You could post the last 30 lines here. You may need `strace -f` if the application starts several processes.

Comment: @HaukeLaging  No, it doesn't abort, it just keeps trying to connect indefinitely.  I used the `-f` flag and have about 90,000 lines of output; the strings I mentioned above aren't there.  The last block of lines is clearly related to me closing the program with Ctrl+C, but I've edited in a different short block that's nearly repeated frequently throughout the output and might be relevant.

Comment: Now check what file descriptor 45 is (I guess some socket): `ls -l /proc/25845/fd/45` (You obviously have to do that while the process is still running)

Comment: @HaukeLaging  Yes, it's `socket:[1734756]`

Comment: You can use `lsof` for determining which process is on the other end of the socket.

Comment: @HaukeLaging `lsof` produces massive amounts of input, including many lines containing the socket number `1734756`.  All of the lines I've found so far are of the form `{COMMAND} 20079 {TID}   user   45u   unix 0x0000000000000000    0t0    1734756 type=STREAM` where `{COMMAND}` is `mullvad-g`, `sandbox-i`, `ThreadPoo`, `Chrome_IO`, or `MemoryInf`.  I've tried reading about `lsof`, but there's a lot.  How does this help me find the process on the other end of the socket?